# Is there a good way to inherit a Builder class to add more options?

Tags: java, builder

If I try to inherit a builder to add more options, I get an unwanted requirement that options be set in a certain order. For example, let me build two builders for class java.awt.geom.Point2D. In the base builder, we can only set the X, but in the second builder, which extends the base builder, we can also set Y:

```
private static class PointBuilder{
  private double x = 0.0;
  protected double y = 0.0;

  PointBuilder withX(double x) {
    this.x = x;
    return this;
  }

  Point2D build() {
    return new Point2D.Double(x, y);
  }
}

private static class PointBuilderWithY extends PointBuilder {
  PointBuilder withY(double y) {
    this.y = y;
    return this;
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

  Point2D pt1 = new PointBuilder()
      .withX(5.0)
//      .withY(3.0)  // withY() doesn't compile, which is the intended behavior
      .build();

  // I can use a PointBuilderWithY only if I set the Y option first.
  Point2D pt2 = new PointBuilderWithY()
      .withY(3.0)
      .withX(5.0)
      .build();

  // If I set the X option first, the Y option doesn't build!
  Point2D pt3 = new PointBuilderWithY()
      .withX(5.0)
      .withY(3.0) // Won't compile! withX() didn't return a PointBuilderWithY
      .build();

  System.out.println(pt1);
  System.out.println(pt2);
  System.out.println(pt3);
}
```

If I call withX() before withY(), the withY() method won't compile, because the withX() method didn't return the PointBuilderWithY class. The base PointBuilder class doesn't have the withY() method.

I know that I can add an abstract withY() method to the base class, but that defeats the point. I want to limit the use of the withY() method to only those objects that need it. In other words, I want the compiler to enforce the restriction that withY() can't be called when using the first PointBuilder. At the same time, I don't want to tell my users that the options must be specified in a certain order, because that would be confusing. I prefer to write foolproof systems. Users expect to specify options in any order, which makes the class easier to use.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In `PointBuilderWithY` override all of `PointBuilder`'s methods  to return `PointerBuilderWithY` instances.

```
private static class PointBuilderWithY extends PointBuilder {
  @Override
  PointBuilderWithY withX(double x) {
    return (PointBuilderWithY) super.withX(x);
  }

  PointBuilderWithY withY(double y) {
    this.y = y;
    return this;
  }
}
```

Comment: Only override them in the subclass. Leave the parent class as is.

Comment: This is the correct solution.  Try it.  If you are referring to the `pt1` example, this change won't make that example compile.  But it will make `pt3` compile ... which is what you want / need.

Comment: Okay, I tried it, and to my surprise, it gave me exactly what I wanted. Thank you to both of you.